# Sporadic Pending Order function | MQL4

Tags: mql4

So I have an EA which places a Pending Order at the opening price of the current candle, and expires at the end of the current candle.

My code is below, I have even printed an error function in order to diagnose any errors that may occur, however, according to the EA, a pending order is placed so no error appears.

Sometimes a pending order is actually successfully executed, and other times, it tells me a pending order has been placed successfully, but no pending order appears on the chart.

There are no error messages.

Clearly there are no errors, so it must be something to do with my coding. What am I missing here? Why does it sometimes placed a pending order on the chart, and others times it decided not to?

Many thanks.

```html
if(<Conditions are met>){

   int      pendingExpiration          = Period() * 60;
   double   candleOpenPrice            = iOpen(Symbol(),0,0);
   double   pendingOrderExecPrice      = NormalizeDouble(candleOpenPrice,Digits); 
   
   if(!OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUYSTOP,3,pendingOrderExecPrice,100,<sl>,<tp>,0,1,Time[0] + pendingExpiration,0)){
               
         RefreshRates();
         
            Print("Error on pending order "+IntegerToString(GetLastError(),0)); 
         
   }
         
   else {
            
    <confirmaion email function>
         
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I see is the Digits thing:

Yours:           `NormalizeDouble(candleOpenPrice,Digits);`

What I know:     `NormalizeDouble(candleOpenPrice,_Digits);`

Notice the underscore.
Although not sure whether this causes the errors.
Your call to `candleOpenPrice` just might sometimes return too many (or few) digits that can not be casted by the erratic call to _Digits.